# Pandas slicing with if condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column based on the simple logic but it does not work.
I'd like to create a new column named 'Commodity' with a simple logic:

```
if df['ID'].str[:3] = 'FWD': 
    df['Commodity'] = df['ID'].str[3:6]
```

My DF looks like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['FWDUSD921','FWDNZD344','EUR'], 'Volumes': [10,20,33]})
```

If no match, leave space blank (or put 0 - does not matter)

I tried lambdas, if, and apply methods but keep getting error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression here

---

```
df.assign(Commodity=df.ID.str.extract(r'^FWD(\w{3})'))
```

```
          ID  Volumes Commodity
0  FWDUSD921       10       USD
1  FWDNZD344       20       NZD
2        EUR       33       NaN
```

---

***Regex Explanation***

```
^               # asserts position at start of line
FWD             # matches FWD exactly
(               # matching group 1
  \w{3}         # match 3 characters that match a-zA-Z0-9_
)               # end of matching group
```

---

If there are any other requirements for what a defines a "currency string" (maybe only letters?), you can replace the `\w` with that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a mask with your condition, and use it with `.loc[]`

```
mask = df['ID'].str[:3] == 'FWD'
df.loc[mask, 'Commodity'] = df.loc[mask, 'ID'].str[3:6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
s = df['ID'].str[:3].eq('FWD')

df.loc[s, 'Commodity'] = df['ID'].str[3:6]
```

Output:

```
          ID  Volumes Commodity
0  FWDUSD921       10       USD
1  FWDNZD344       20       NZD
2        EUR       33       NaN
```

Comment: You don't have to use `.loc[]` in the right hand side of the assignment? Interesting!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```py
import numpy as np

df['Currency'] = np.where(df['ID'].str[:3]=='FWD', df['ID'].str[3:6], '')
```